# Java: calculate Pi via recursion (if else only)

Tags: java, recursion, pi

i have to calculate with this [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXU00.gif) the number Pi.
Note: beginner in java.
My idea till now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(quadraticFractionSum(20) * 6.0));
}
static double quadraticFractionSum(double counter) {
    if (counter == 1000.0) {
        return counter;
    } else {
        return counter + 1 / (quadraticFractionSum(counter + 1) * quadraticFractionSum(counter + 1));
    }
}
```

the problem is it takes forever to calculate that :/
- solved: Answers: Alain O'Dea + Balwinder Singh

new problem :
the code is not calculating pi - solved answer: Aimert

much appreciated for your help

Comment: Try to extract "quadraticFractionSum(counter+1)" to a variable, you are doing the same calculations twice for no reason. That should help a bit with the time.

Comment: @Aimert i tried it in eclipse, but got a stackoverflowerror :/

Comment: @Aimert I just saw your answer :D thx mate but i've done it with the while method a while ago. but my professor wants that in recursion, which is tbh a pain in the ass :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems (one possibly minor, non-fatal):

1. Severe for performance: unnecessary quadratic complexity of recursion
2. Severe for correctness: You start at the wrong count and the recursive case is wrong
3. Minor, but instructive: unnecessary use of floating-point and possible rounding errors

**Unnecessary quadratic complexity of recursion**

---

You recompute the recursion quadratically which is intensely expensive.  You're doing 2^980 recursive calls (note I'm talking about individual method invocations not stack depth here) when you only need to do 980.  That's a bad cost explosion.

**Start at the wrong count and the recursive case is wrong**

---

Secondly, you need to start **count** at **1**, not **20** and you need to do **1/counter^2 + quadSum(count+1)** in the recursive case.  I use **1.0d/counter^2** there to ensure Java uses **double** arithmetic.  Otherwise it would use integral arithmetic and give only **1** or **0** as results.

The base case (stop approximating at 1000 iterations) should return **1.0d/counter^2** for that last iteration.  I chose instead to make the base case **iterations + 1** and return **0.0d** because I think it is cleaner.

**Unnecessary use of floating-point and possible rounding errors**

---

Lastly, your base case may not be working due to accumulated floating-point errors.

**==** is a risky proposition for **double** or any floating point number.  Precision errors accumulate with every calculation and can easily lead to it not equating to a whole number for your base case.

**counter** should be **int**.  Try that and see if it speeds up.

**Proposed solution**

---

Here is code demonstrating my proposed fix for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(quadraticFractionSum(1) * 6.0));
}
static double quadraticFractionSum(int counter) {
    if (counter == 1001) {
        return 0.0d;
    } else {
        return 1.0d / (counter * counter) + quadraticFractionSum(counter + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: good point but not an answer to the question, which was "why is this so slow" :) The risk is also not present when only using full integer values, http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint

Comment: @zapl I figured by slow the OP meant non-terminating ;)

Comment: that would indeed be very slow

Comment: @zapl I see the quadratic complexity issue now. I've addressed that I think.

Comment: @Alain O'Dea thx alot :) now the problem is my code obviously doesnt calculate Pi :D , pretty new to this sorry for posting the last code as an answer :/

Comment: @manonmars okay.  That's another problem and another question so accept this and ask a new question and I'll follow you to it and help.

Comment: well obviously i can only post every 90 minutes :D

Comment: @manonmars in the mean time track down some questions you can answer to build rep. That limit gets lifted once you break 200 I think.

Comment: @manonmars hook me up with that accept and upvote now if you please :D Gotta feed the habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(quadraticFractionSum(1) * 6));
}

static double quadraticFractionSum(int counter) {
    if (counter == 1000) {
        return 1d / (counter * counter);
    } else {
        double quadraticFractionSum = quadraticFractionSum(counter + 1);
        return quadraticFractionSum + 1d / (counter * counter);
    }
}
```

when you do 1 / whatever, it's giving you an integer result because both numbers are integers. You have to specify you want a double result, otherwise you get zeroes (hence the "1d").

Comment: i hope wont use that besides in exams :D

Comment: @manonmars recursion is actually necessary sometimes in industry too. You should almost certainly prefer iterative algorithms in Java, but certain algorithms are inherently recursive and understanding it sets you above.

Comment: hm.. you took away my correct answer and no offense to @AlainO'Dea but his code doesn't really work :( it gives a wrong value

Comment: @Aimert sorry about that. This got complicated because the question scope got expanded after I answered the original question correctly.  I voted up your answer and strongly encourage others do the same.

Comment: It's ok, i know this is not a competition, sorry. Anyway your answer is more detailed so it'll be better in case someone looks for something like this :)

Comment: @Aimert you'll build rep quickly. If you can snap out clear, concise, correct answers like this, you'll be soaring quickly.